# Can't ping vagrant from ansible by ad-hoc command

Tags: ssh, ansible, vagrant

I am using vagrant now.

I can ping virtual machine from local terminal.

I want to use ansible to ping that vagrant virtual machine:

```
$ ansible 192.168.33.101 -m ping -u root
```

But got error:

```
192.168.33.101 | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Permission denied (publickey,password).\r\n",
    "unreachable": true
}
```

I added that IP in `/etc/ansible/hosts` file:

```
192.168.33.101
```

Both local and virtual machine have ssh installed. So why can't reach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to configure your ssh connection. The Ansible `ping` module naming is confusing. The `ping` module actually builds up an ssh connection to verify the ability to login and that a usable python is configured.

So like the `ping command` can tell you that the network connection to a remote host is working the `ping module` tells you that Ansible is capable of running commands on the remote host.

Look at the [official documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/guide_vagrant.html) how to setup ssh connection to your Vagrant box.

Basically you will need something like this:

```
ansible-playbook --private-key=~/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key -u vagrant -i .vagrant/provisioners/ansible/inventory/vagrant_ansible_inventory playbook.yml
```

For ad-hoc commands something like this:

```
ansible --private-key=~/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key -u vagrant ...
```

Comment: Thank you. Now I don't want to run a playbook but just only a `ad-hoc` command.

Comment: Same goes for ad-hoc commands. Your ad-hoc command ping failed because you didn't define the ssh-key installed by vagrant on the machine.

Answer (score 0):

I did the following to get this working. I added the public key of my host machine to the authorized keys in vagrant vm.

```
# on host machine, copy the public key
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

# on vagrant session
sudo vi ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
# add the above copied key here and exit
```

Now you can access and run ansible from host machine to vagrant machine.

Also many times, by default user on vagrant machine is **vagrant**, so you can also run the following command

```
ansible 192.168.33.101 -m ping -u vagrant
```

Hope this helps!